# Automate Connect-AzureAD using powershell in Azure Devops Pipeline for SPN

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am doing the following for connecting to the AAD usingazure devops Pipeline for Powershell task

1. created a SPN and granted the Permissions for the Graph
2. While using the code below to connect using the access token it says [Error Pipleline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L54On.png)

My code is simple As below

```
    Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force
   $context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
   $graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
   $aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken      
  
   Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
   Write-Output "AAD Token is  $($aadToken)"
   Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $context.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken -MsAccessToken $graphToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id 
   $outputusers= get-azureaduser -Top 5
   Write-Output "The users are listed $($outputusers)"
```

Could you please let me know if i missed any detail. The SPN is just a devops pipeline one and its not a AAD user. So the token may be invalid for authentication.

What do i need to do for the SPN to be a user in AAD. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you use `Get-AzureADUser` to call Azure AD Graph, so try to add Azure Active Directory Graph `Directory.Read.All` permissions, can solve your problem.

[image]
[image]

By the way, the `-MsAccessToken $graphToken` command can be omitted.

Comment: Carl Zhao it is pretty awesome answer for the authentication problems. Thanks

Comment: @CarlZhao is the Directory.Read.All permission the same for both the Microsoft Graph API as the Azure Active Directory Graph? In other words, it doesn't matter which of the two APIs you choose as long as it is permission Directory.Read.All?

Comment: No, the functions of these two endpoints are different, so you need to select the Directory.Read.All permission under Azure Active Directory Graph api.